# Expectation value of symmetric random variable restricted

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Let $X$ be a **symmetric random variable around** $0$ so that $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ we have $\mathbb P(X\leqslant -x)=\mathbb P(X\geqslant x)$. And it's clear that the expectation value $\mathbb EX=0$.

My question is that, given any $\varepsilon>0$, whether or not $\mathbb E[XI_{\{|X|<\varepsilon\}}]=0$ still holds, where $I$ is indicator function.

Intuitively I think it's right, such as taking $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$. But when I try to show it in general case, I have to proof that the following Lebesgue integral
$$E[XI_{\{|X|<\varepsilon\}}]=\int_{|X|<\varepsilon}X\;{\rm d}\mathbb P=0$$
and I'm stuck here. Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that $X$ is symmetric wrt $0$ can also be done by stating that $X$ and $-X$ *have the same distribution*.

Then consequently $f(X)$ and $f(-X)$ have the same distribution for every Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

For $f$ you can take the function prescribed by $x\mapsto x1_{[0,\epsilon)}(|x|)$.

Then we find that $X1_{[0,\epsilon)}(|X|)$ and $-X1_{[0,\epsilon)}(|-X|)=-X1_{[0,\epsilon)}(|X|)$ have equal distribution so that they have equal expectations.